# Trigger Event on auto-expiring documents - Mongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb

I wrote a simple insert to mongo DB data base using

**db.log_events.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )**
Which will be deleted automatically after 60 minutes.

I would like to know how to invoke a script (kind of java method) whenever a MongoDB document expires automatically. 
I need this to remove/delete files on my system whenever there is a removal of document from mongo DB collection.
Please answer me with the possible choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not have triggers or support for calling scripts.

The only option I know of is to write a program which follows the changes to the oplog collection and perform some action when appropriate

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to know Is there any way to invoke the method whenever a change to oplog collection occurs?

Comment: No, you will have to use a tailable cursor and filter the oplog documents

Comment: just one more clarification. Is profiler logs auto deleted records? I am unable to see them in system.profile.find({op:"remove"}).

Comment: No idea, post a new question as we are getting away from what you originally asked.

Comment: I just saw your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750366/scheduler-for-deleting-physical-files-based-on-mongo-db-auto-deleted-records) and think you might be confused. The oplog is the oplog.rs collection in the database called local http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/local-database/#local.oplog.rs

Comment: Yeah. but, from documentation, oplog only works if we enable replication. My aim is to delete the physical files if the documents(stores paths) are auto deleted by running a scheduler. So, I am checking profiler for the removed documents but profiler is not storing any auto removed file records. So I need a way to do this without setting replication.

Comment: I am unaware of any way to accomplish this without the oplog. Alternatively delete the documents manually instead of using a TTL index

Answer (score 0):

mongo db use system.js for such requirement ,you just need to create a new collection system.js in database and in that collection make required function.call it in your global file.Done!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can we write a script which is invoked when the records are auto deleted from the document?