# Scheduler for deleting physical files based on Mongo DB auto deleted records

Tags: java, mongodb, scheduler

I am trying to implement a **scheduler** which will run every 24 hours for my **java** application. The scheduler is associated with Mongo DB records. I would like to **delete** the files which are named exactly same as the **ID of Mongo DB auto deleted documents**.
I think scanning the whole documents of a collection and cross checking with the file names would not be the good solution.

What is the best way to do?
I have tried using the logs of profiler but, It is not storing the auto deleted records.

Comment: Can you clarify the setup? You have a collection in MongoDB that parallels a collection of files, and documents will be deleted from the collection. Will they be deleted "automatically" as in using a TTL index? Or deleted by some client process?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I am using TTL indexing on Mongo DB collection.which stores the location of files which are created during a method.

Answer (score 0):

Go for quartz scheduler.
Check http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/